# how can I turn a url encoded as a URIComponent into multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, url, multipartform-data

I have a URI that that I need to be a .qsf file to be encoded as multipart/form-data. The reason for this is I want to run an API call that only accepts .qsf files with a content type of multipart/form-data. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the URI:

```
https://docs.google.com/a/qualtrics.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTzqoFdc9Tuspk2Rwv5drAi1YY1D6bmZKBE4ei0puDKLRG4BQKoneQLbmyTeZ6KKtMczONQectYqGXL/pub
```

I have searched the web and cannot find how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) class creates `multipart/form-data` parameters.

```
var urlparams = "param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3";
var formdata = new FormData();
urlparams.split('&').forEach(param => {
    let [key, value] = param.split('=');
    if (value === undefined) {
        value = "";
    }
    formdata.append(decodeURIComponent(key), decodeURIComponent(value));
});
```

When you send `formdata` as the parameter to the API it should be formatted appropriately.

```
xhr.send(formdata);
```

Comment: What are the urlparams?

Comment: It's the string containing the URL-encoded parameters that you need to convert.

Comment: There don't seem to be any parameters in the URI you posted.

Comment: @Barmar - you are a star on SO, for sure.  But normally your answers are clearer.... I'm trying to track what's going on here, and I'm not quite able to.  `formdata` appears to be declared without `let` or `const`, and the _use_ of `formdata` doesn't seem to be explained.... maybe I'm just not used to / familiar with the `FormData` class...?

Comment: I've added a little more code and a link to the FormData documentation.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn’t clear. It doesn’t have any parameters as it’s just a JSON file that’s URI encoded. I have access to the JSON file - that’s not encoded - as a string or an object if that’s easier. But basically I want to take that JSON file, whether it’s URI encoded, a string or an object and turn it into a .qsf file which is content type multipart/form-data. Is that possible? To be completely clear that link I provided is a link to a google doc that has the URI as text in the doc